# Routing in Asp.Net MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting `"VirtualPath must be a non-empty string starting with ~/."` error

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: VirtualPath must be a
>   non-empty string starting with ~/. Parameter name: virtualPath

in the below code:

```
public class RouteTableHelper
    {
        public static RouteCollection UserSiteRoutes()
        {
            RouteCollection routes = new RouteCollection();
            RegisterRoutes(routes);
            return routes;
        }
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
              ...............
            routes.MapPageRoute("catalogAnnualreport2013", "catalog/annualreport2013", "www.facebook.com");
            .............
        }
   }
```

Comment: You can't route to an arbitrary URL, it has to be within your website, if you want to go to some other site you will have to do a redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routing doesn't extend past your own site. Might it be better to use the standard MVC routing setup and to make a controller action that redirects the user to Facebook?

```
public class CatalogController:Controller
{
    public ActionResult Annualreport2013()
    {
        return Redirect("http://www.facebook.com");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.mappageroute(v=vs.110).aspx), the third parameter should be a virtual url (including application root `~`). Hence the name of the parameter: `physicalFile`.

Something like:

```
routes.MapPageRoute( "catalogAnnualreport2013" // routeName
                   , "catalog/annualreport2013" // routeUrl
                   , "~/yourPage.aspx" // physicalFile
                   );
```

Where `yourPage.aspx` is one of your own ASP.NET ASPX pages. You can't route to an external url, like `www.facebook.com` in your question.

All redirecting to external sources need to be done from a Controller action (using [`Controller.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect(v=vs.118).aspx)), or [`Response.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309(v=vs.90).aspx) in an ASPX page or ASHX handler.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to redirect to external URL.Please give the response as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `MapPageRoute`is only used for WebForms routing ([MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.mappageroute(v=vs.110).aspx)). I've always used the [`MapRoute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routecollectionextensions.maproute(v=vs.118).aspx) extension in MVC applications.